# thirdparty DLL with /Fixed header option

Tags: winapi, dll, linker, createprocess, rebasing

I have a program `A.exe` which is linked dynamically with `a.dll`.

`a.dll` is a 3rd party DLL that is linked with the `/FIXED` option. I know this because its DLL Characteristics is 0 when I see it with `dumpbin`.

When I start `A.exe` from Explorer, nothing bad happens, and it seems the loader carefully rebases other DLLs.

But, when I want to start `A.exe` from another program `B.exe`, and use `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute()`, `A.exe` is not opened and an error appears in Windows Event Viewer:

> Critical Error: invalid base addr., GetlastError: 487.

I know the problem might be solved by using `Rebase.exe` and rebasing all DLLs, but why is there no problem when I open `A.exe` from Explorer? How can I resolve the problem programmatically in my code?

I don't have access to the DLL provider.

Comment: That is odd. Out of curiosity, what is the preferred (I guess, fixed) load address of a.dll?

Comment: need look under debugger, what is happens in both case

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it is default address for 32 bit Dlls :0x1000000